# Flamebait topics - how do we want to deal with them?

Tags: discussion

In my experience, most testing forums have a few contentious topics that attract much heat, and very little light.  The "certification" fracas is one example - I'm sure people can come up with others.

Given that this is a Q&A site, rather than a debating platform - are there topics that we would want to close on sight? Or should these always be dealt with on a case by case basis?

Answer (score 1):

Generally such things get closed as "closed as subjective and argumentative". [Example](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-do-you-write-a-great-bug-report). In the beginning, we'll probably close too many too fast, such as [the books one](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing) - I think that should be a community wiki question as it is on many other sites.

Comment: the "is OK but community wiki" vs "should be closed" has always been hard to judge IMHO